Issue with WiFi Connectivity on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I am experiencing an issue with WiFi connectivity on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS system. The problem started recently after a new WiFi connection was set up in our office. Here are the details:
Issue Description: When I connect to the new office WiFi, the internet works for about 20 to 30 minutes. After this period, the internet speed drops, and a question mark appears on the WiFi symbol.
Additional Issue: Once the connection drops, I am unable to connect to any other WiFi networks, including my mobile hotspot, without restarting my system.
Specific to One Network: This issue only occurs with the new office WiFi. I do not face this problem with other WiFi connections.
Connecting to this new office WiFi is crucial for my work. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?
Thank you for your support.

As you yourself have pointed out this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Talk to your office IT guys and find out what they have changed.

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

@DavidDE It is working fine for other ubuntu users in my company.
